# GA4 Events are not showing up as Conversions after set

Tags: google-tag-manager, google-analytics-4

I'm sending server events from my website server through GTM server-side to GA4. It's being correct received as an Event, however when I set it as a Conversion, it does now show up on the Conversion section and does not fire as Conversion as well.

It's been more than 24h after I set the events as conversion.

Could anyone by any chance know the reason why it doesn't work as expected for the events?

I tried to remove it from conversions, add it again, add events name manually but nothing has changed.